# Bigquery converts my string field into integer while loading json file with Python

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

{"number":"1234123"}
I am assigning this data to my Bigquery table using bigquery.LoadJobConfig in python. The type of my number column in my bigquery table is string. When I do the load operation, it converts the data type in my bigquery table to integer. How can I solve this?
The file type I loaded: json.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
create_disposition=bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,autodetect=True
)
```

Additionally: When I set autodetect to False, I get an error like Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to pass a `BigQuery` `schema` to prevent this situation, instead to use `autodetect=True`, example :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("number", "STRING")
    ],
    create_disposition=bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
    autodetect=False
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    table_id,
    location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
    job_config=job_config,
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

In this example I set the schema of `BigQuery` table and `autodetect` to `False`.
If you use `autodetect` to `True`, you can't have a control on your field types.

You can check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#python) to have more information.

Comment: @ygzdevop have your solved your issue ?